# Меню Аккордеон, трёхуровневое

Tags: html, css, javascript

Здравствуйте, посоветуйте, пожалуйста, меню в стили Аккордеон, трёхуровневый. Есть [вот такой](http://js.aceweb.ru/users/2/index/1/index.html), он полностью из js. А мне желательно на `html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jquery-ui accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/)
Создаете несколько вложенных акордеонов.

```
<div id="accordion">
<div>
<h3><a href="#">First</a></h3>
<div><div id="accordion2">
<div>
<h3><a href="#">First2</a></h3>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>

<div>
<h3><a href="#">Second2</a>
<div>Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh.</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3><a href="#">Third2</a></h3>
<div>Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis.</div></div>

<div>
<h3><a href="#">Second</a>
<div>Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh.</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3><a href="#">Third</a></h3>
<div>Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis.</div>
```

Comment: Как поместить внутрь вкладки еще вкладку?

    <div id="accordion">
    <div>
    <h3><a href="#">First</a></h3>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    </div>
    <div>
    <h3><a href="#">Second< /a><h3>
    <div>Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh.</div>
    </div>
    <div>
    <h3><a href="#">Third< /a></h3>
    <div>Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis.</div>
    </div>
    </div>

Comment: Просто берете и запихиваете. Только имя измените. О_о

Comment: Так я сейчас так и сделал, запихал изменил имена айди тоже изменил, и 3 влкдадки новые стали отображатся там где я их помостил, но при их нажатию закрывается радительская вкладка

Comment: Используйте stop_propagation();

Comment: еслиб я знал что такое stop_propagation(); яб не писал сюда) объясните пожалуйста куда его нужно вписать?

Comment: Допустим, у вас все вкладки всех аккордеонов имеют класс vkladka.
Тогда пишем: 
    $('.vkladka').click(function(){
      stop_propagation();
    });

Эта функция запретит родителю получать информацию, что по нему нажали, если клик пришелся на ребенка.

Answer (score 0):

Вот [пример](http://grimon.net/test_menu.php) на списках, а, сори, у вас вертикалка. Хотя то, что есть, можно спокойно переработать.

Comment: Я имел введу сам Аккордеон на списках, можно и на дивах, но трёхуровнего, а в вашей ссылке drop down стиль меню.
Сам я переработать не смогу, поэтому ищу готовую загтовку трехуровневого аккардеона, который раздвигается по клику как гармошка.